# Moduli stack of l-adic sheaves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, stacks, algebraic-stacks, l-adic-sheaves

Let us work over a field $k$. Then for any smooth affine group scheme $G$ over $k$, we can consider the stack quotient $BG := [\text{pt} / G]$ which classifies étale $G$-torsors.

Let $\ell$ be a prime different to the characteristic of $k$. Then one such $G$ we can consider is the finite abelian group $(\mathbb{Z}/\ell^n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ viewed as a constant group scheme. Then $B((\mathbb{Z}/\ell^n\mathbb{Z})^\times)$ equivalently classifies locally constant rank 1 étale $\mathbb{Z}/\ell^n\mathbb{Z}$-sheaves.

My question is roughly whether there exists a moduli stack for rank 1 $\ell$-adic sheaves.
To be more precise, let us define $E_n$ to be the substack of $B((\mathbb{Z}/\ell^n\mathbb{Z})^\times)$ classifying constructible rank 1 étale $\mathbb{Z}/\ell^n\mathbb{Z}$-sheaves.(Edit : constructible generalises locally constant so the arrow is the wrong way around.) Presumably modding by $\ell$ gives maps of stacks $E_{n+1} \to E_n$. Then I can form the (homotopy) limit $E := \varprojlim_{n \geq 0} E_n$ say as categories fibered in groupoids over the category of affine schemes over $k$.

**(Added) Question 0 : Is $E_n$ an algebraic stack?**

**Question 1 : Have I done anything illegal?**

**Question 2 : Does $E$ classify rank 1 $\mathbb{Q}_\ell$ sheaves?**

**Question 3 : Is $E$ an algebraic stack?**

Comment: I don't think there is a substack of $B( (\mathbb Z/\ell^n \mathbb Z)^\times)$ classifying constructible $\mathbb Z/\ell^n\mathbb Z$ sheaves. This would be so if constructible sheaves were a subset of locally constant sheaves, but it's the other way around: locally constant rank $1$ $\mathbb Z/\ell^n\mathbb Z$ sheaves are a subset of constructible rank $1$  $\mathbb Z/\ell^n\mathbb Z$ sheaves.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you for pointing that out. I will change the question accordingly.

Comment: I think $E$ should be the classifying stack of the (affine) group scheme $\underline{\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}}^{\times}:=\varprojlim_{n} (\mathbb{Z}/\ell^{n} \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ in the pro-etale topology. To be precise, I think it should classify pro-etale $\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}$-torsors.

Comment: If you say 'rank 1', presumably you mean rank 1 everywhere, right? Then you're just working with lisse sheaves/locally constant sheaves/local systems of rank 1, so no need to talk about constructible sheaves. Re Q0: yes, the classifying stack of a finite group is an algebraic stack (even a Deligne–Mumford stack).

Comment: Yes I mean rank 1 everywhere. Do you mean to say that for a torsion étale sheaf, being locally constant rank 1 with respect to a finite stratification is equivalent to just being locally constant rank 1?

Comment: The precise statement is that a constructible sheaf $\mathscr F$ is locally constant if and only if all cospecialisation maps $\mathscr F_{\bar x} \to \mathscr F_{\bar y}$ for specialisations $\bar y \rightsquigarrow \bar x$ are isomorphisms. So you could be constructible of rank 1 everywhere but not locally constant, but that's a very unnatural condition. But I don't know where your rank 1 condition is coming from, so I can't tell you which variant is the 'correct' one.

Comment: Examples that are not locally constant look like $\bigoplus_i f_{i,*} \mathscr F_i$ for a finite stratification of $X$ by locally closed subschemes $f_i \colon Z_i \hookrightarrow X$, where each $\mathscr F_i$ is locally constant of rank 1 on $Z_i$.

Comment: Thank you for the example! I was originally interested in one dimensional continuous l-adic reps of fundamental groups. Perhaps I should've directly asked whether there is an algebraic stack classifying 1-dimensional l-adic étale local systems.

Comment: Feel free to edit the question to ask what you now want to ask - there's no need to preserve a record of what you said before (which is available by examining the edit history anyways).